Picking the right ICA
I am exploring ICA for a project. I know that ICA is not deterministic which is a problem for me. Some one said that they run ICA 100 times and pick the result that occurs the most. So I ran 1000 times and found the most common result occurred 4 time. I was expecting more. Does anyone have better idea? I am new to ICA.

"I know that ICA is not deterministic" that seems wrong. For the same input, you get the same output.

"I ran 1000 times and found the most common result occurred 4 time." This is a bit confusing here: even assuming you ran the same experiment with different noise a 1000 times, it's mathematically almost certain that you never get the same result, assuming your result is unquantized. Like, fundamentals of probability theory: if some random variable (here: the output of whatever you're doing) has a continuous probability density function, then the probability of any single value from $\mathbb R^N$ occuring is 0, because the integral of a bounded function over an interval of width 0 is always 0.

So, I think to actually help you, you need to really write down what kind of signal, with what kind of noise, you subject to ICA, to get what kind of result, and how you determine that two results are identical.
